# c++ How do I create a class that uses variables of it's own type

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to create a class that has variables of it's own type, and am running into problems. Here's what I would like to do:

```
Class myClass
{
    private:
        myClass a, b;
    public:
        void myFunctionA()
        {
            SomeOtherClass.somePointerToMap = &a;
        }

        void myFunctionB()
        {
            SomeOtherClass.somePointerToMap = &b;
        }
};
```

Any help is appreciated, it's for a text based game that would require 100's of if statements to move the player around if I can't get this to work.

Comment: You can't do it. Go back a step and describe (in detail) the problem this is meant to solve, maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @BenjaminLindley, you might want to read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Impossible even for 1 house. Can the compiler reserve enough memory for a house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house that is big enough for Jack plus another house...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a forward declaration and the class representing a recursive type will have to use pointers:

```
class myClass
{
private:
    myClass* a;
    myClass* b;
```

Comment: I don't know how you could possibly have enough information to know that this is a solution to his problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The intention is clear: to build a recursive data structure. My proposal is the most likely way to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that because

1) having an instance of a type requires that the type is complete, and a class is only complete after the closing brace of its definition.

2) A class holding an instance of itself would be infinitely big.

You need to store a pointer or a reference to `myClass`.

Comment: So under the `private:` I'd need to go like this:

Answer (score 1):

The size of a class is at least one byte.

But if a class contains two copies of itself then it must be at least two bytes.

But if it's at least two bytes (and contains two copies of itself) then it must be at least four bytes.

But if it's at least four bytes (and contains two copies of itself) then it must be at least eight bytes.

... and so on ... :-)

You can have a class that contains two REFERENCES to instances of the same class:

```
struct X {
    int x;
    X &a, &b;
    X(int x, X& a, X& b) : x(x), a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

building the first instance is not trivial because references must be set up in constructor and cannot be changed later. Still it's possible to build a network with some trickery... for example

```
extern X x1;
extern X x2;
extern X x3;

X x1(1, x2, x3);
X x2(2, x3, x1);
X x3(3, x1, x2);
```

And after that `x1.a.b.a.a.b.b.a.b.a.a.a.b.a.x` is 1.

You can finally have a class that contains POINTERS to instances of the same class. This is a quite common pattern (for example for binary trees):

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int value, Node *left, Node *right)
        : value(value), left(left), right(right)
    {}
};
```

the advantage with pointers is that you're not forced to specify an instance (you can use the null pointer instead) and that you can also change later what a pointer is pointing to. Unfortunately the syntax is a bit more annoying (requires `->`).

Another very easy option (but it works only for trees and not for arbitrary topology) is a class containing a container of instances of the same class, for example:

```
struct Node {
    int x;
    std::vector<Node> children;
    Node(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

This works because the `children` container may also be empty (so the size doesn't explode to infinity) and internally is managed using pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create pointers, if you want to create variable of it's own type. Normal variables (non-pointers) are complete types, which you cannot create inside "own type". Pointer is incomplete type.

So following is permissible,

```
Class myClass
{
    private:
        myClass *a, *b;//incomplete type
....
}
```

But this is not possible,

```
Class myClass
    {
        private:
            myClass a, b;//complete type
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Any pointer (even a pointer to a forward declared class) is a valid complete type.

Comment: No pointer is not complete type. You may refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx

Comment: And where in that link does it say that pointers are incomplete types?